# Send Whatsapp message to user from website

Tags: whatsapp

I have one icon of WhatsApp. When the user clicks on it, It asks for the mobile number. I want to send a text to user's WhatsApp. Is there any way to achieve it?

I have tried [WART](https://github.com/mgp25/WART) Whatsapp but it no longer exists.
I have also searched about [whatsmate](http://whatsmate.net). but it is not providing free test API.

I have also used `whatsapp://send?text=text` but it is redirecting to WhatsApp web. 
I want to send a direct message to a user whenever the user hits the button.

is this possible?

Comment: It looks like WhatsApp doesn't provide an API for you to send direct messages, probably so that users can't be spammed with lots of automated messages. I don't think you can do this currently. https://blog.cloudrail.com/whatsapp-api-how-to-use-the-whatsapp-chat-api/

Comment: I'm quite sure they also want people to use their app, instead of some other services that would use their API.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Twilio to integrate with the new WhatsApp API. https://www.twilio.com/whatsapp